# Cannot get selected type from GetTypes

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, expression

I want to initialize classes in the following assembly which are inheriting from the `EntityBase` class using reflection.

I am guessing the lambda expression is correct but I don't know how to get those 2 classes (there are 2 classes in assembly which inherit `EntityBase`) from `types2`.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("X:\\Workspace\\Operations\\ItemSupplierSetupRequest\\Main\\Source\\ItemSupplierSetupRequest.Entity\\bin\\Debug\\xxxx.ItemSupplierSetupRequest.Entity.dll");
IEnumerable<Type> types2 =
    a.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType.ToString().Equals("xxxx.ItemSupplierSetupRequest.Entity.EntityBase"));
```

I also tried

```
var result =
    a.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType.FullName.Equals("xxxx.ItemSupplierSetupRequest.Entity.EntityBase"));
```

but don't know how to use or to check if this returns those 2 classes?

Answer (score 3):

Your queries should probably work. But there is no need to use `Equals()` or to compare the types using strings. You can use (assuming `EntityBase` is in a referenced assembly and its namespace is in a `using`):

```
a.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(EntityBase))
```

Keep in mind this will not return all types that inherit from `EntityBase`, only those that inherit from it *directly*.

Comment: Thanks for answer - but I don't know how to use Activator.CreateInstance for instantiating the objects from IEnumerable<Type> types2 or var result that I tried? Any clue on that? Also I don't know how to check if my query is returning correct result- ofcourse I can't debug the lambda expression. Thank you!

Comment: If you have another question, then ask another question, so that others with the same problem in the future can find it. And you can debug the result of the lambda. In VS debugger, you can click on “Results View”.